value divided by 100 does not return a decimal place although both the divident and the divisor are declared as data type float in c languages
I am about to solve the readability task from the CS50 course. This should become a programm that counts letters and words to use them in the Coleman-Liau -Index. Therefore i would like to divide the return value of the class which counts the letters  by 100 . Too see if it works i output the value by printf. For example if i enter the value Whatever, the value 0.08 should be output. But Instead it outputs 0.
I have definied the variable score as float and did the the same with the return value with the return value of the class compute_score. I also definded the divider and the divisor  with the same datatype. I have even specified in the placeholder that exactly 2 decimal places should be specified.
Unfortunately, I can't think of where the error lies. I would be very happy about help.
below you can read the code.
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

float compute_score(string text);

int main(void)
{

    string text = get_string("Text: ");

    float score = compute_score(text);

    printf("%2.f", score);
}
float compute_score(string text)
{

    float divider = 100.00;
    float letter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
        if ((text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z') || (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            letter++;
        }

    }
    return letter / divider ;
}
float compute_score1(string text)
{


    return letter / divider ;
}


I don't know what compute_score1() is supposed to be, but it cannot compile. Why are you using float rather than double? And what is get_string()? and string, for that matter?

@user207421: get_string is a function declared in cs50.h. It is part of the CS50 library. Most examples in the CS50 course use float, but it is explained later that you can get more precision by using double.

@user207421 It's from the strange class known as CS-50 where they use typedef char* string;, teaching students bad practices... get_string will be something like printf + scanf and probably silent memory allocation too.

And are we expected to know all that? from wherever this CS50 course gets taught? Wherever it is, I'm probably thousands of miles away. Questions here are supposed to be self-contained.

Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste. Your posted code does not reproduce the problem, because it does not compile, because your function compute_score1 is using the undeclared variables letter and divider.

"the value 0.08 should be output. But Instead it outputs 0" --> VTC as typo: "%2.f" directs printf() to print 0 digits after the decimal point.

It's not really a typo though, it's a beginner who doesn't know how printf format stuff goes. Would be better to close as a duplicate, or if you can't find one, leave it open. Putting the digit on the wrong side of the . sounds like a potentially recurring question.

In printf you need to type .2. Digits immediately after the % is the "field width" (padding with spaces etc if fewer digits than the number are there). The digits after the . is the precision so that's where you want the 2 to be. If you don't specify a digit after the . it gets taken as zero, so no decimals, which explains your result.
printf("%.2f", score);

